# Context.Consumer isn't using the value from Context.Provider

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the Context API to render UI components based on a user's logged in status. The Context.Consumer seems to be getting the value from the Context.Provider, but that value is being stored on a key of `1`, and the Consumer's child function is getting handed the value from either `0` or `_currentValue`.

How do I get the Consumer to use the newly Provided value instead of the default value?

Some reduced code snippets...

`<Layout />` wraps all pages, `<MenuContent />` renders inside `<body />`

```
const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext("defaultValue");
```

```
function Layout() {
    return (
        <Provider value="newValue">
          <body>{props.body}</body>
        </Provider>
    );
  }
```

```
function MenuContent() {
  console.log('ConsumerObject:', Consumer);
  return(
    <Consumer>
      { value => console.log("value:", value) }
    </Consumer>
    );
  }
```

The console prints:

```
value: "defaultValue"
```

and

```
ConsumerObject: {
  '$$typeof': Symbol(react.context),
  _context: {
    '0': 'defaultValue',
    '1': 'newValue',
    '$$typeof': Symbol(react.context),
    _calculateChangedBits: null,
    _currentValue: 'defaultValue',
    _currentValue2: 'defaultValue',
    _threadCount: 2,
    Provider: { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.provider), _context: [Circular] },
    Consumer: [Circular],
    _currentRenderer: null,
    _currentRenderer2: null
  },
  _calculateChangedBits: null
}
```

So, I'm seeing that `newValue` is on the `Consumer` object, but it doesn't seem to be in the right place so as to access it as the docs demonstrate.

Hopefully I explained that well enough... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it seemd normal. In your Consumer log, the type of `Consumer` is `[Circular]` instead of `Symbol(react.context)`.